# How to have a type check for a string

Tags: python, string, format

I am making a program whereby a user can enter their personal details, such as first name, last name and date of birth, and this data gets saved in a separate text file. I need to make a format check to ensure the first and last name entered by the user is a string, i.e. no numbers in between.

I have used a `try: except:` to ensure the data input for weight is in a specified range and isn't a character.

```
valid = False
while not valid:
    try:
        weight = int(input("what is your weight?: "))
        if 50 <= weight <= 100:
            valid = True
        else:
            print("please enter sensible weight")
    except ValueError:
        print("please enter valid weight")
```

Comment: What's your try on this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not reinvent the wheel, your python version already has this capabilities:

```
>>> 'abc'.isalpha()
True
>>> '123'.isalpha()
False
>>> 'ab1c'.isalpha()
False
>>> '123'.isalnum()
True
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if a given string has any digit we can use :

```
DIGITS = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0']
def check_digits(sample_string):
    for character in sample_string:
        if character in DIGITS:
            return False
    return True
```

Note that you can always change the `DIGITS` list to include any unwanted character.

Comment: You can always use `isalpha()` method as well but one downside of using that method id that it doesnot allows flexibility if you wanna include some more unwanted symbols in future,